# Is it alright to post my PHP and mySQL Login script for review and improvements?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I would like to post my script here, if I get the okay I will post it, or is there another place that I should post my script and link to it?

Please Advise

Comment: It's ok I think but your question is more suited for meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One typically does not post code to StackOverflow unless one has a specific question about it. You can, however, host your project in a [Google Code](http://code.google.com/) repository and use the "request a code review" feature.

Comment: There's 414 questions tagged code-review here with question like "can I improve this code"

Comment: Also there is refactormycode.com; though I've never used it. (http://refactormycode.com/)